# Read Notification data if app is in killed state

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want to read Notification if application is in killed state. Read in terms of.. I want to fetch user id field from notification body and allow that particular user to access my location. and simultaneously update location on fireBase database. Please suggest some solution to handle this condition only if app is in suspended or killed state. and It should get done only on notification arrived.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Enable the background modes.
[image]

Implement the `performFetchWithCompletionHandler` delegate method in `AppDelegate`.

```
        - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
            [self sendHitsInBackground];
               completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
```

}

```
    - (void)sendHitsInBackground {

        __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier backgroundTaskId =
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
            //Do task
        }];

        if (backgroundTaskId == UIBackgroundTaskInvalid) {
            return;
        }

                   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:backgroundTaskId]; 
}
```

**NOTE:-** Each call to this method must be balanced by a matching call to the endBackgroundTask: method.